# Can i export and import my database to 'flatten' out any memory page issues

Tags: database

I have an SQL database that I have been working with a while,
Maybe I am going down the road of prematurely optimizing...

But i have been adding new tables and adding/modifying fields in this database as the application develops - note the application is in full uses so we are adding to the database using entity migrations.

My worry is by adding lots of small changes i am creating a fragmented memory model.

Is it worth at soem point stopping the db and exporting and then reimporting again.
Would this recreate the db in a layout as if i had created it all in one go without all the additions etc.

I am conscious about additional fields ending up in totally different pages etc.

Any ideas? Am i off the mark here?

Its not a high usage db so the difference is probably marginal...

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the specific database engine you're using, but you are almost certainly barking up the wrong tree here - on modern hardware, this kind of optimization is so marginal you only notice it in edge cases. I've worked on dozens of database projects, with lots of migrations and other DDL changes, and I have *never* run into this problem.

I would put my energy into:

- modern, fast hardware (lots of RAM, SSDs)
- query optimization
- possibly running the code that refreshes your indexes (update statistics or similar) on a schedule.